# Why do I have to perform cast to object inside value tuple?

Tags: c#

Here are types of data that I have

`Title = string`

`Id = int`

Why does that

```
var docs = _context
            .Documents
            .Select(x => new { x.Title, x.Id }) // it's IQueryable thats why I cannot go straight to the value tuple 
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => (x.Title, (object)x.Id))
            .ToList();
```

require `(object)` cast before int  `Id`

in order to satisfy this overload?

```
public void Test(ICollection<(string Text, object Value)> data)
{
}
```

**Without cast:**

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<(string Title, int Id)>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<(string Text, object Value)>'

Meanwhile this works fine

```
public void Test((object a, object b) data)
{
}
```

---

```
int myint = 5;
Test(("a", myint));
```

What's going on?

Comment: `(string, object)` is a different type than `(string, int)`. In the second example, the compiler can handle that (because it knows which _type_ of tuple to create, or maybe tuples are even co-variant), but it cannot handle an assignment from `List<TypeX>` to `ICollection<TypeY>`.

Comment: `List<T>` and `ICollection<T>` are invariant in C#, it can be a reason

Comment: I don't think _variance_ is really the problem here, `ValueTuple<string, int>` does _not_ inherit from `ValueTuple<object,object>`. They are simply completely different types, hence `ICollection<>` of different types are also different types.

Comment: FYI you can use `AsEnumerable` instead of `ToList` when you want to go from `IQueryable` to in memory Linq and it will not require an extra list to be created.

Comment: @Joelty: Because a `List<(string Title, int Id)>` is *not* an `ICollection<(string Text, object Value)>` but it is an `ICollection<(string Text, int Value)>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same reason why a `List<long>` can't be implicitly converted to a `List<int>`, but `long`s can be implicitly converted to `int`.

If you can accept that `List<long>` and `List<int>` are unrelated types, then you should be able to accept that `ICollection<(object, int)>` and `ICollection<(object, object)>` are unrelated types.

`(object, int)` and `(object, object)` are unrelated value types, just like `long` and `int`. The only reason why the compiler is able to convert from `int` to `long` them is because the language specification explicitly allowed this "widening value type conversion". Similarly, [tuple types can be implicitly converted if each of the element types can be implicitly converted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples#assignment-and-tuples).

If you still don't understand this, consider this code that I could potentially write in the `Test` method:

```
data.Add((new object(), new object()));
```

If a `List<(object, int)>` were passed in, that `Add` call would not work, would it?